# remote debug connect fails => "no logon servers available to service logon request"

Tags: c#, debugging, dns, offline

I believe I understand why I am getting this -- but could be wrong... I believe that the PC I am running msvsmon.exe (the pc to debug) is a domained PC, and I have been given it to work on without its domain server, it is offline to its domain sever. I do have local administrative account and privileges - to do all - but not attach my VS studio to the msvsmon running on this PC....

I added a 2nd lan adapter -- and have a private connection.... still no...

Can I make this 2nd Lan connection be Workgroup'ed? --- and thus by-pass the domain server logon name requirement....

Is there a setting for MsVsMon.exe -- to say hey --- this is a LAB evironment -- give up and allow the connection....

The unauthorized connection works..... but -- that I have learned is not allowing the .PDB files to match and thus no symbols!!!!!!!!

So any way -- at all?????

To have remote debugging with symbols --- any possible way?????

Thanks in advance....

best regards,
Kevin Waite

NOTE: ===> One added addition characteristic..... despite the PC being debugged is offline to its domain controleler . . . . I can create a new Admin user and successfully remote desktop to this PC - - - one would think that if I can connect for remote desktop I should be able to connect for remote debugging ..... !@@@@!

Answer (score 0):

I usually only have success with remote debugging if I'm logged on with exactly the same credentials on both machines.

This works (for me) if I'm logged on to the domain as the same user on both machines.

It also works if I create a local non-domain account with the same name and password on both machines, and ensure that I'm logged on using that on both machines.

In all other cases, I get the same problems as you do...

Comment: How do you create a local non-domained account????????????? that would solve my problem!!!!!!!! ----- fyi, my credentials are the same ..... thanks -- hope this non-domained account concept works? I may have done it when I made a new user.... and so... but please let me know how you did it.. thanks greatly..... regards, Kevin

Comment: In cases it works for you and the PC being debugged is a domianed PC, what happens if it's domain is offline? I am guessing but my problem is one of having the server logon authorization requiring the domain controller to be online.... if not, then this should be working, but it solidly is not....

Answer (score 0):

Unless someone has a way for 'workgroup' connection on LAN adapter #2 to
coexist on a domained controlled PC via its LAN adapter #1. This seems impossible.

From above, recall, I am trying to debug on a domained PC that is offline to its
domained controller, and the remote debug connection fails with no service available
to processes the log-on request....

And thus the only solution to connect successfully to this PC was to switch it
to a Workgroup PC for remote debug connection.

The credentials: user name and password must be identical between both the
PC with VS 2010 and the PC to be debugged running MsVsMon.exe....

The user must have on the debugged PC security privilege 'logon on to service' set.

One can archive the domained configuration for restoration by force taking a Windows
checkpoint prior to switching to workgroup configuration.

best regards,
Kevin Waite